# Wordpress Multisite WWW redirect issue (Root site only)

Tags: wordpress, redirect, web

I am running WP 3.71 Multisire within subdirectories not subdomains. When I type "WWW" in the URL for the main (ROOT) site for any webpage it redirects me to the home page. The other 2 sites  and the pages within these two load with or without the WWW just fine.

I did turn off all the plugins. Turned off (switched) the template. And the problem still exsists.

I would like for the main (ROOT) website to redirect with or without the WWW like the other two, but have not been able to figure out the issue with why it doesn't work properly. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

WP config file is:

```
 define('MULTISITE', true);
 define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
 define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mywebsitename.com');
 define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
 define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
 define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]
 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
 RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to check your webserver configuration but wordpress saves the url in the database so it can redirect at leass you make a function to it.
This plugin could help : [Wordpress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)